# Calculate the gradient and Hessian of $x_0^T(X\operatorname{Diag}(w)X^T)^{-1}x_0$ w.r.t. vector $w$ in matrix calculus?

Tags: derivatives, matrix-calculus

I'm trying to calculate the Hessian matrix of the formula
$$
f(w) = x_0^T(XWX^T)^{-1}x_0
$$
where $w=(w_1,\cdots ,w_n)^T$, $W=\operatorname{Diag}(w)$ is a diagonal matrix that has $w$ as diagonal elements, $x_0$ is a column vector, $X$ is a matrix.

To calculate the first-order derivative, do I need to first transform $W$ into $$\sum_i w^T e_i E_i,$$
where $e_i$ is a column vector whose $i$-th element is $1$ and others $0$, and $E_i$ is a matrix whose $(i,i)$ element is $1$ and others $0$? Any reference is appreciated.

Comment: This is one of those instances in which the difference between \text{} and \operatorname{} is blindingly conspicuous. Contrast these:
$$
\begin{align}
& x_0^T(X\text{Diag}(w)X^T)^{-1}x_0 \\
& x_0^T(X\operatorname{Diag}(w)X^T)^{-1}x_0
\end{align}
$$
The difference is not only the spacing difference that you see here, but rather, with \operatorname{}, the spacing depends on the context. With \text{}, it does not. I edited the question accordingly. $\qquad$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$\def\o{\operatorname}\def\t{\o{Tr}}\def\v{\o{vec}}\def\d{\o{diag}}\def\D{\o{Diag}}\def\p#1#2{\frac{\partial #1}{\partial #2}}$For
typing convenience, define the symmetric matrices
$$\eqalign{
A = X\,\D(w)\,X^T \quad\qquad B = A^{-1}x_0x_0^TA^{-1} \\
}$$
and use a colon as a product notation for the trace, i.e.
$$\eqalign{A:B = \t(A^TB) = B:A}$$
Write the function in terms of the new variables.
Then calculate the differential and gradient.
$$\eqalign{
f &= x_0x_0^T:A^{-1} \\
df &= x_0x_0^T:dA^{-1} \\
  &= -x_0x_0^T:A^{-1}dA\,A^{-1} \\
  &= -B:dA \\
  &= -B:X\,\D(dw)\,X^T \\
  &= -X^TBX:\D(dw) \\
  &= -\d\left(X^TBX\right):dw \\
  &= -\d\left(X^TA^{-1}x_0x_0^TA^{-1}X\right):dw \\
\p{f}{w} &= -\d\left(X^TA^{-1}x_0x_0^TA^{-1}X\right)
 \;\doteq\; g\quad\big({\rm gradient}\big) \\
}$$
where the $\d(M)$ function takes the main diagonal from its matrix argument and returns it as a column vector, while the $\D(v)$ function takes its vector argument and creates a diagonal matrix.

**NB**: The properties of the trace allow the terms in a colon product to be rearranged in many equivalent ways, e.g.
$$\eqalign{
A:B &= B:A = B^T:A^T \\
CA:B &= C:BA^T = A:C^TB \\
}$$

---

A comment asked for the Hessian.

If you define
$$\eqalign{
y &= X^TA^{-1}x_0 \\
dy &= -X^TA^{-1}X\,dW\,X^TA^{-1}x_0 \\
Y &= \D(y) \\
}$$
then you can write the gradient as
$$\eqalign{
g &= -\d(yy^T) = -Yy \\
}$$
The Hessian is the gradient of this, so
$$\eqalign{
dg &= -\d(dy\,y^T + y\,dy^T) \\
 &= -2Y\,dy \\
 &= +2Y\Big(X^TA^{-1}X\,dW\,X^TA^{-1}x_0\Big) \\
 &= 2YX^TA^{-1}X\,dW\,y \\
 &= 2YX^TA^{-1}XY\,dw \\
\p{g}{w} &= 2 YX^TA^{-1}XY \;\doteq\; H \qquad\big({\rm Hessian}\big) \\
}$$
$(Y,dW)$ are diagonal matrices corresponding to the $(y,dw)$ vectors, therefore
$$dW\,y = Y\,dw$$
The Hessian is obviously symmetric, and since $(X,Y)$ appear an even number of times, its positivity is determined by the $A^{-1}$ term, which in turn is determined by $\D(w)$, which in turn is determined by the signs on the individual $(w_k)$ elements.

Comment: This is very helpful! Ultimately I'm trying to prove convexity of $f(w)$ by proving $v^THv \geq 0$ for any $v$, where $H$ is the Hessian matrix. Could you give some thoughts on it?